# Android HTTPPost and HTTPResponse error

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm working on an app and having this problem. I'm using PHP as back end server and JSON as data transfer technology. But problem is that, Http POST and RESPONSE are not working. Http GET is working and user is being logged in but no response is getting back and POST also not working.

Please help me if you understand the problem.

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);                                   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);                                                                       
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

}

Comment: Hey, please be more specific about your questions. Could you please share code snippet?

Comment: Please post your coding which you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm using JSONParser and code is alright.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
HttpResponse response;

    try { 
       URI url = new URI("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
       HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
       json.put("x",x);
       json.put("y", y);        

       StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
       post.setEntity(se);
       response = client.execute(post);

       if(response!=null){
           InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
           in.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```